# Replace a part of the Worksheet with dataframe

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, replace

How should I code for the following condition:
if the excel sheet has 100 rows and 20 columns and new dataframe has 30 rows and 5 columns, only 30*5 data should be replaced in the worksheet, rest of the cells should have have old data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a great guide on how to ask a question.  Following this will yield much more pertinent answers!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by importing the excel file to pandas via pandas.read_excel().

```
import pandas as pd
excel_data = pd.read_excel(FILE_NAME)
```

Next, you want to replace the data you want to replace, for example by:

```
excel_data[0:30][0:5] = new_data.values
# this assumes you have 30 rows and 5 columns of new data
```

and then save the excel data with:

```
excel_data.to_excel(FILE_PATH)
```